# Python setup.py install_requires not found when hosting private python repo

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

We have our private repo where we're installing python packages from.

We are installing our packages with the following command:

> $ pip install --index-url https://repo.example.com/py example-package

Our setup.py looks like the following:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='example-package',
    version="0.1.0",
    description="This is an example package",
    author="John Doe",
    author_email="john-doe@example.com",
    license="Private",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    platforms=["linux"],
    install_requires=[
        'pydantic',
        'requests',
        'xmltodict'
    ],
)
```

The problem we face is that the `install_requires` packages cannot be installed. The error is like this:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pydantic (from example-package) (from versions: none)`

I think happens because the `install_requires` searches on our private python repo for the requirements. But I'm not sure. If this is the case how can I make the setup.py install the `install_requires` from pypi.

And what could be the issue otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue independently and would like to share the solution with you.

**The Problem:**

I encountered an issue while running the following command:

> $ pip install --index-url https://repo.example.com/py example-package

By specifying the `--index-url` parameter, the command only searched for packages within our private repository.

**How I Solved It:**

The solution was straightforward. Instead of using `--index-url`, I replaced it with `--extra-index-url`. This change allows the command to look for packages in the default public PyPi repository while also searching for the specific package in our private repository. However, it is crucial to ensure that the package name does not match an existing public package.

> $ pip install --extra-index-url https://repo.example.com/py example-package